# CS0103 Error in Visual Studio on simple project containing only a textbox and button

Tags: c#, wpf

UPDATE *** My error had to do with the computer I was using and not being part of a FIPS validated algorithm. That error only appeared after I closed Visual Studio and tried to compile the default blank WPF form. I did the exact same thing on a personal computer and it compiled as expected. ***

I'm familiar with creating windows form using C#.  I looked into methods to change the look of my forms, similar to using skins, and was told that it would be easier if I I used WPF....ok.

In an effort to become familiar with WPF, I picked up a book, "MASTERING_WINDOWS_PRESENTATION_FOUNDATION" and it was slow moving with a discussion on MVVM and data binding (new topics to me). I felt the I could learn the difference between WPF and Windows Forms much faster if I first tried to create a simple WPF application. Then, as I read, I could see how something done in a very familiar way  using Windows Forms, is done using WPF.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck right out the box!

Using VS2017, I created a new  WPF App (.NET Framework) I then added a text box and a button. I created a name for both as this does not appear to be automatically created like with Windows Forms.  I then double click on the button and a method block is created in the MainWindow.xaml.cs file. I proceed to add text to the textbox
 (`txtbox_1.Text="Hello;"`).

I noticed a few things:
1.) The `InitializeComponent();` call in the `MainWindow()` method is underlined and corresponds to the CS0103 Error
2.) Intellisense did not recognize the textbox. I typed out the full name and it created an error when I was done. (Same CS0103 Error)

I looked through stackoverflow but found articles about Xamarin. I've heard of this as a way to write code for Android but do not know how it relates to what I'm trying to do.

What am I missing?

Here is my XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btn_browse" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="524,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtbox_1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,93,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="363"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is my MainWindow.xaml.cs file:

```
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void SimpleMethod()
        {
            txtbox_1.Text = "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your current problem, more of a comment: WPF is fundamentally different. I know it's hard and boring and you want to get coding, but read the book and follow MVVM. The old way of windows forms might still work, but it's like putting two horses in front of your new fancy sports car. Just don't. Whatever you do now trying to apply Windows Forms knowledge, you will throw it away anyway. Read the boring parts. It's worth it.

Comment: What error? I actually think your post is too broad, can you choose just one question?

Comment: Does your project build when creating an empty WPF project without adding anything?

Comment: @nvoight - I agree and my plan is to read the book. I was just looking for an early success. Boring is ok for me.

Comment: @Sinatr - I received a CS0103 Error: 'The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context and The name 'txtbox_1' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @Brandon When I create the new project, a blank form appears with no errors.  As soon as I added a control, the error appears.

Comment: did you by any chance messed up the namespace?

Comment: @Daniele - I did not change the namespace. I left it as the default that corresponded to the project name when I created a new project.  I am at the initial stage.  I'm currently going through a tutorial provided by Andy below and it mentions that I need to add a ViewModel first.  Right now, I don't know how to do that and its not clear how to do it from the tutorial.  I suspect I will figure it out shortly.

Comment: instead of reading irrelevant tutorials you could have followed StackOverflow guidlines and provided a [MCVE]

Comment: @Ash - I felt I was providing minimal and verifiable examples. I didn't feel that providing the default Visual Studio code was necessary. I walked through my steps and kept it simple. Also, how do you determine a priori that a tutorial is irrelevant?  I learned something very early in the tutorial provided.... that a view model needed to be added.   I just have not figured out how.

Comment: useful != relevant. view models are used in many WPF apps. But WPF app can be developed in exactly same manner as winforms app (without view models and bindings). providing the default Visual Studio code is not necessary. " I then added a text box and a button" <- that should have resulted in some non default code

Comment: Got it. I see that my post was marked down. It may be due to the missing code.  I updated my original post with the code from two files: MainWindow.xaml and MainWndow.xaml.cs.

Comment: InitializeComponent() is auto-generated in a WPF app, there is an extra build step that takes the XAML file and turns it into C# code.  Sounds like you skipped a step somewhere, be sure to pick the WPF project template to get started.

Comment: @Hans  -- thank you for mentioning that there is an extra build step.  I initially tried to build from this step (like I would using Windows Forms)  In VS2017 I chose File/New/Project WPF App (.NET Framework) and the OK. I kept the defaults, added a text box and a button.

Comment: @ASh   I see what you mean. That would not have happened had intellisense worked as I would have just chose the correct object.   I made the change and still have the same error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion.I prefer to stop here as I see that this post has already been marked down 2 times.This would suggest that I should be pretty far along in WPF before asking questions about WPF. Go figure.

Comment: After a weekend grind with WPF, I can now say that I understand it and see the benefit.  My issue had more to do with the firewall of the computer I was originally using. It was beneficial to 1st create two identical applications using WinForm and WPF, both using code behind and then re-writing the WPF to take advantage MVVM.  I had thrown myself into a WPF book that jumped right into MVVM. It gave the impression that you needed to know MVVM to move on.  That is not true. It's going to take time for me to be as proficient in MPF as I am in WinForms but I think its going to be worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error had to do with the work computer I was using ... something to do with FIPS. You should be able to create a new WPF project and compile the blank form without error. I did the exact same thing on a personal computer and it compiled as expected. I was also able to reproduce a WinForms project as a WPF using code behind without error. Implementation using MVVM took a significant amount of time since the concept of view models was new to me but, in the end, it's not bad.

Answer (score 0):

That InitializeComponent(); line is hugely significant since it is that instruction makes your xaml turn into UI.
If it's underlined then your partial class for code behind isn't matching up with the xaml.

You will have something like

Either that or you're missing some fundamental references should have been added when you started your project.

I suggest you just bin your sln though.

Just delete it and start again.
Create a new wpf project.
Hit f5.
If it crashes and burns your VS install is broken.

Anyone and everyone will tell you to learn MVVM. And you should.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31915.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-1.aspx?Redirected=true

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32164.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-2.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: Thank you for the links. Unfortunately, I got stuck quickly.  Its at Add A ViewModel section.  I do not see anyway to add a ViewModel and the example is unclear. I right clicked on the solution and I also checked the toolbox for a ViewModel control.  I guess that I am to create a new class (which I did) and then build.  No luck.  I have a blank MainWindow (no controls), the default text in the MainWindows.xaml.cs file, and the recommended text in a new class file called class1.cs.

Comment: A viewmodel isn't a control, it's a class. Add > Class. And you need an instance of it as the datacontext of your view. It needs to expose a property with a value and you need to bind that to the text of a textblock - or something. There are working samples linked from both articles.

Comment: Thank you Andy. I did create a class. I called it class1.cs.  I tried to create an instance using class1 myClass = new class1(); in the MainWindow.xaml.cs file under the MainWindow() Method but that did not work. (It was not recognized by intellisense). I don't understand what you mean by "datacontext of your view" and binding to text of a textblock.  I suspect I will eventually get there using the tutorial you supplied, but right now its not providing enough information to me to reproduce the expected results and move on.  Thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: The article isn't intended to teach you absolutely everything about wpf by itself. When you think "what's a datacontext then"?  The thing to do is google it. Google wpf datacontext and there's a stack of hits. It's where bindings look for properties, by default. It's a dependency property which is marked as inherits. That means it's value is inherited down the visual tree. Google any of those terms you don't understand.

Comment: Andy, I mentioned that I'm not just now jumping into this. I purchased a book and have put a fair amount of time into it. In fact Googling is also what brought me here. I mentioned that I didn't understand the language you used to highlight that I am new to WPF so that future correspondence would take this into account. I've seen the terms of course, just have not had any success in using them.  My post wasn't intended to learn everything, I have a pretty thick book for that. I was just looking to get past a hurdle.  Thanks again for the assistance you provided.

Comment: Instead of using the code behind the class (the .xaml.cs) which would then tightly couple you to that logic. You use a ViewModel class and in the .xaml.cs do something like ‘DataContext = myClass’ so then myClass becomes the object you use for logic of the UI. This means that if you wanted to in the future, you could make a myClass2 which manipulates the data differently and quite easily set the DataContext to this instead.

Comment: @Coops  Thank you for that explanation. That helped out a great deal in filling the gaps of understanding the different between the Windows Forms approach and WPF.  I did what you suggested and am now able to move on.

Answer (score 0):

That means that your MainWindow class actually does not inherit from System.Windows.Window class.

I don't see a reference to System.Windows in your class. This is the namespace, where the WPF Window basic class is defined. So your Window base class can reference a Window class from some other namespace, and, that's why it has no InitializeComponents() method and can not reference the property from XAML. Try first adding this using directive to code behind class. If that doesn't do the task, check if your project has a reference to System.Windows. If there is no System.Windows in your reference manager (this could be if your project is set to compile in .NET 4.0) add references to PresentationFramework, PresentationCore and WindowsBase.